# Glassfish adapter in Eclipse Juno missing

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

So I have downloaded Glassfish Application Server bundle from below site in my Eclipse Juno EE.

http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/juno

That contains App Server runtime and Glassfish server tools. I can see them in Installed Software so Im guessing they installed ok.

However when I want to add new Server instance, Glassfish is missing from the server adapters list for some reason.

I researched it online and did in few different ways as well (ie. dwonload from Eclipse marketplace or Download Additional Server Adapters thing from within Add Server dialog), but its still the same - Glassfish server is not available to be added.

If anyone have any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was being a fool and even though I had workspace Java set to 1.6 JDK, for some reason my Windows JAVA_HOME was set to 1.5.....
When I changed that, GLassfish adapater showed up.