# Glassfish 3.1.2.2 Eclipse Plugin for Juno

Tags: eclipse-plugin, glassfish-3, eclipse-juno

Somehow, at some point, I installed this version of the Eclipse Glassfish Plugin for Juno:

Oracle GlassFish Server Tools   2.0.1.201207240829

I'm trying to help a co-worker install it too.  But the latest version from the marketplace is

Oracle GlassFish Server Tools   2.0.1.201201241920

I think I must have gotten it from [here](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/juno/) which is referenced in [this accepted anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13771636/19269) but that site is now dead.  That site is also referenced in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623190/glassfish-adapter-in-eclipse-juno-missing)

Does anyone know what the heck is going on with Eclipse Glassfish Plugin for Juno and Glassfish 3.1.2.2, and/or a different place from where we can get the version I seem to have?

Or else, tell me where I can report this problem to the team that maintains this plugin other than SO?

Comment: I just sent a message to users@glassfish.java.net - let's see if that helps...

Comment: And here is an issue tracking the problem: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISHPLUGINS-363

Comment: @hwellmann thanks!  I couldn't figure out where to report issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle is currently migrating the GlassFish plugins - see 
https://blogs.oracle.com/piotrik/entry/migration_of_eclipse_plugins_java
for details.

The old update site http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/juno/ is working again (despite appearing empty when you open the URL in your web browser).