# Glassfish server adapter not shown in list in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I successfully installed Glassfish Tools for Kepler.
However besides Apache, Basic, JBoss and ObjectWeb I do not see an entry for GlassFish in server wizard `(File->New->Other->Server)`.

I tried to install Glassfish Tools both from Eclipse Marketplace and from server wizard's "Download additional server adapters".

Glassfish Tools plugin is installed
[image: Glassfish Tools plugin is installed]

Not shown in server type list
[image: Not shown in server type list]

jre is fine ($JAVA_HOME set to the default value)
[image: jre is fine ($JAVA_HOME set to the default value)]

Similar questions didn't help:
[Glassfish adapter in Eclipse Juno missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623190/glassfish-adapter-in-eclipse-juno-missing)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried to install several components from Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse Kepler (no matter which, because I deleted all of them afterwards!) http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/oracle-enterprise-pack-eclipse-kepler#.U8Ul03WSy00

After installing, the dialog with warning "Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse requires Java 7 or higher. Continue to configure a compatible Java VM." appeared. I specified path to jdk (same as in picture above, same as my $JAVA_HOME) and restarted Eclipse. **After this everything works.**

**UPDATED.** As I found out, the key is in `eclipse.ini` file. If this file starts from

```
-vm
/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_40/bin
```

(well, depending on your jdk path) Glassfish is shown in server adapter list. If not - Glassfish is not shown.

Answer (score 10):

For those who are still having trouble getting this to work, it seems like the GlassFish plugin started to require **Java JDK 8** for Luna at some point.

Yesterday I had GlassFish running in Eclipse Luna on JDK 7. Today I reinstalled Eclipse and the GlassFish Tools via Marketplace but the GlassFish Server did not show up in the "Define a new Server" view, although JDK 7 was selected as default VM.
After I installed JDK 8 and made it my default VM, everything worked just fine.

*Edit*: I found this on the official Glassfish Marketplace confirming my assumption. The Glassfish Plugin for Eclipse now requires JDK 8 for Eclipse Mars and Luna (Kepler only requires JDK 7): http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools

Comment: This also happens for WebLogic. I had the same issue even after installing the Wls plugin (included into oepe). I got to see the server in the list just after installing JDK 8 and putting it as a default runtime. It looks like an Oracle policy.

Comment: A further note for others still facing the issue: Specifying the -vm in the middle of the file as instructed in https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini doesnt work. Make sure to specify it at the top of the file.

Answer (score 2):

This was a tricky one. On a windows machine/laptop, just add these two lines to your eclipse.ini. see a copy of an eclipse.ini below
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform_4.3.1.v20130911-1000
**-vm

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin**
 
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-install
C:\Eclipse\EclipseEE431
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m

Answer (score 2):

In my case  I solved this issue by using Eclipse Marketplace.Type "glassfish" in the search box then install it.That's all.

Answer (score 0):

in Eclipse market place search for glassfish server adapter for eclipse mars. there is link to install in one of the hyperlink.