# Add Glassfish Server to Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have installed the GlassFish Tool and the Oracle Enterprise pack :

[image: first image]

[image: second image]

because I can't find the Adapter:

[image: third image]

But nothing happens and I can't add the Server.
[image: fourth image]

What's going wrong?

Comment: Can you upload your images to an image hoster and add the plain links to your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I have challenged it.

The solution was to change the eclipse.ini file.
see here:

[Glassfish server adapter not shown in list in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758298/glassfish-server-adapter-not-shown-in-list-in-eclipse)