# Installing GlassFish server in luna

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, eclipse-luna

I am trying to install GlassFish server manually and have installed the GlassFish tool from Eclipse market place.

However, when I go to
Windows > Show Views > Other > Server > Servers

New->Server still no option for GlassFish is show.

I am still unable to see the GlassFish server option
How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the *Glassfish Tools*? The correct way is:

1. install Glassfish (outside of eclipse)
2. click Window->Preferences
3. click Runtime Environment
4. click Add
5. (probably you won't find Glassfish otherwise go directly to 13.) click link Download additional server adapters
6. choose Glassfish Tools
7. Next
8. Finnish
9. Reboot Eclipse!
10. click Window->Preferences
11. click Runtime Environment
12. click Add
13. choose GlassFish
14. choose GlassFish installation directory (possible if you finnished 1.)
15. Finnish

Now you should be able use the New Server Wizard within the Server View.

Comment: Hi Nikla... I have installed glass fish outside eclipse.. the problem is when i am trying to do no 5 download server adapters.. i am not getting any option for glass fish

Comment: I found an answer of an other question where it's mentioned that for the actual GlassFish Plugins you have to use JDK8! (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29576635/3437758) Maybe you can give this answer a try?